# Windows Obtaining Standby Ram C++

Tags: c++, windows

Is it possible to obtain the amount of currently in "Standby" on Windows (using C++)?  And if so, how would that be done?

Comment: You will need to research what "Standby" is mapped to, but once you have done that this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965225(v=vs.85).aspx should let you retrieve the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

If

> Cache Bytes + Sharable pages on the standby and modified lists

is good enough for you (from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965225(v=vs.85).aspx)), then you can use [GetPerformanceInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683210(v=vs.85).aspx) and inspect the `SystemCache` member of the [PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684824(v=vs.85).aspx) you get.